# Get content from URL data by class or ID using JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, curl

I was thinking about solution all night but I can't figure it out.

I have PHP code which download URL content:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$data = get_data($url);
```

and I want to get content from divs or whatever from this by class name or ID so I send this variable to JS like this:

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

    alert(data); 
    //alert shows all code of downloaded URL
    //$( ".content" ).html( data );
    //this line show whole page but I want only specific element/class
</script>
```

How can I achieve this? Let's say I want to get content of H1 tag with class="productMainTitle" from "data" variable in Javascript ?

Any tip would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends exactly what you want to do.

**1. Send only the relevant fragment of the HTML client-side**

See @artm's answer.

**2. Send all the HTML client-side and sort it out there**

```
<script>
    var $data = $("<?php echo $data; ?>");
    $data.find("h1.productMainTitle").appendTo(".content");
</script>
```

*assume `json_encode()` is unnecessary. If I'm wrong, then reinsert.*

If you want only the "h1.productMainTitle" fragment this is less efficient than (1), but if you want further fragments, then this is a viable approach.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot, it works perfect :) And I guess json_encode is needed becouse without this code shows whole page again ^

Answer (score 2):

Use DomParser

```
var parser = new DomParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
```

then get the element you want from the document as usual

```
doc.getElementById("id")
```

and assign its html to your div.

Edit:

```
$("#content").html(doc.getelementById("col1-755").text());
```

Comment: Thanks for quicke answer. Unfortunatly it isn't working.  
  
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;  
alert(data);  
var parser = new DomParser();  
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");  
$('.content').doc.getElementById("col-755").text();

In variable data I have only source code of downloaded page not xml code I think.

Comment: Are you trying to get #col-755 's text from the loaded document? Then just use doc.getElementById("col-755").text();

Comment: Yes, but I need to assign this value to div on my page

Comment: Thanks a lot for all answers! I prefered to use Roamer-1888's answer with find :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<iframe>` to open child pages by URL and hide them if necessary.

For now we can do without URL: create empty frame and force write some html right into it.

Try the following script by steps (push the buttons) to see what's going on:

```
<body>
  <button onclick="createFrame();">createFrame</button>
  <button onclick="getElement();">getElement</button>
  <button onclick="closeFrame();">closeFrame</button>
  <button onclick="showExtractedElement();">showExtractedElement</button>
  <script>
    var frame
        , frameDoc
        , elem
        , htmlData = '<html><body><h1 class="myClass">Hello</h1></body></html>'
          /*somehow we got this string containing html data*/

    function createFrame()
    {
      frame = document.createElement( "iframe" );
      frame.setAttribute( 'hidden', '' ); // on debug remove this line to see the frame
      document.body.appendChild( frame );
      frame.contentDocument.write(htmlData)
    }

    function getElement( )
    {
      elem = frame.contentDocument.querySelector( '.myClass' )
    }

    function closeFrame()
    {
      document.body.removeChild( frame );
    }

    // the extracted element remains
    function showExtractedElement()
    {
      console.log( elem )
    }

    // call this method from console or script to do all the magic
    function doEverything()
    {
      createFrame()

      getElementFromAnotherPage()

      closeFrame()

      showExtractedElement()
    }
  </script>
</body>
```